# how to access resources on windows phone 8.1 with cordova

Tags: angularjs, cordova, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing a windows phone 8.1 app based on cordova framework, by design, there are some resources need to be loaded in advance, they are txt files with json content actually. The way they are loaded is by using angular $http.get with a relative path to the file as the resource url, something like $http.get('resources/init.json') . The situation right now is, it works perfectly on debug mode, however, an error will be reported when it's published, the error message is : 'Error: The resource is a direct reference to a non-default resource candidate.'

Not sure how could this happen, any ideas?